# "Exception thrown: 'System.FormatException' in Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.dll " in ASP.NET console application C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I am trying to insert a Sqlgeography column from latitude, longitude points to SQL server 2016 but I am getting

> Exception thrown: 'System.FormatException' in Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.dll

I have already installed the Microsoft System CLR Types for SQL Server 2016 on the machine. What is the correct approach to resolve this issue.

```
SqlCommand addpoint = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO " + Helper.TABLE_ALLINDEXPOINTS + "values (@id, @latitude, @longitude, @streetname, @longlat", sqlConnection);
addpoint.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", id);
addpoint.Parameters.AddWithValue("@latitude",Convert.ToDouble(snappedPoints[j]["latitude"]));
addpoint.Parameters.AddWithValue("@longitude",Convert.ToDouble(snappedPoints[j]["longitude"]));
addpoint.Parameters.AddWithValue("@streetname", snappedPoints[j]["name"].ToString());
addpoint.Parameters.AddWithValue("@longlat", SqlGeography.STGeomFromText(new SqlChars(string.Format("POINT({0} {1})", snappedPoints[j]["latitude"], snappedPoints[j]["longitude"])), Helper.SRID));
addpoint.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Error:

> 'ConsoleApp2.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: DefaultDomain): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_32\mscorlib\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\mscorlib.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
>   'ConsoleApp2.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: DefaultDomain): Loaded 'C:\Users\ssindhu\source\repos\ConsoleApp2\ConsoleApp2\bin\Debug\ConsoleApp2.exe'. Symbols loaded.
>   'ConsoleApp2.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: ConsoleApp2.exe): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Net.Http\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Net.Http.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
>   'ConsoleApp2.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: ConsoleApp2.exe): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
>   'ConsoleApp2.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: ConsoleApp2.exe): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Core\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Core.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
>   'ConsoleApp2.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: ConsoleApp2.exe): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Configuration\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Configuration.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
>   'ConsoleApp2.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: ConsoleApp2.exe): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Xml\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Xml.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
>   'ConsoleApp2.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: ConsoleApp2.exe): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_32\System.Data\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Data.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
>   'ConsoleApp2.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: ConsoleApp2.exe): Loaded 'C:\Users\ssindhu\source\repos\ConsoleApp2\ConsoleApp2\bin\Debug\Newtonsoft.Json.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
>   'ConsoleApp2.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: ConsoleApp2.exe): Loaded 'C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.SqlServer.Types\14.0.0.0__89845dcd8080cc91\Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
>   'ConsoleApp2.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: ConsoleApp2.exe): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_32\System.Transactions\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Transactions.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.

This is the table schema:

```
create table all_index_points
(
    id varchar(450) not null primary key,
    latitude float,
    longitude float,
    streetname nvarchar(max),
    longlat geography
);
```

Comment: Please include the details of the exception - in particular which method is throwing it (I'd expect STGeomFromText or the SqlChars constructor) and the error message.

Comment: have you tried adding space before `Values` word?  like `" values` not `"values`

Comment: @JonSkeet I added the error I am getting

Comment: @maulikkansara I tried but still the same error.

Comment: @Sree error indicates that you have enabled the option "Just My Code" (Tools -> Options -> Debugging -> General).
This will skip loading symbol files. disable it and try.

Comment: And in particular, that still doesn't contain any of the details of the exception. Catch the exception, or look at it in the debugger, and you should see the stack trace and the method. All the output about loading assemblies isn't useful - but the exception details would be.

Comment: @maulikkansara, I tried this but still I am getting the error. I have updated my error in the description.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Following are some of the things that needed correction in your code:

```
SqlCommand addpoint = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO " + Helper.TABLE_ALLINDEXPOINTS + " values (@id, @latitude, @longitude, @streetname, @longlat)", sqlConnection);
```

Note the space before values. Also missing a closing bracket.

```
addpoint.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", id);
addpoint.Parameters.AddWithValue("@latitude",Convert.ToDouble(snappedPoints[j]["latitude"]));
addpoint.Parameters.AddWithValue("@longitude",Convert.ToDouble(snappedPoints[j]["longitude"]));
addpoint.Parameters.AddWithValue("@streetname", snappedPoints[j]["name"].ToString());
addpoint.Parameters.AddWithValue("@longlat", SqlGeography.STGeomFromText(new SqlChars(string.Format("POINT({0} {1})", snappedPoints[j]["latitude"], snappedPoints[j]["longitude"])), Helper.SRID));
addpoint.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Also do share the details of your exception along with the possible datatypes of your table fields in case the above does not solve your problem.

**EDIT**

Beside all the above mentioned problems the actual problem that you are facing will be solved by appending the following line before you call ExecuteQuery:

```
addpoint.Parameters[4].UdtTypeName = "Geography";
```

As SQL Server requires you to explicitly set UdtTypeName for parameter of type SqlGeography (and some other types as well, which I am not mentioning here).

So your updated code should look something like:

```
addpoint.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", id);
addpoint.Parameters.AddWithValue("@latitude",Convert.ToDouble(snappedPoints[j]["latitude"]));
addpoint.Parameters.AddWithValue("@longitude",Convert.ToDouble(snappedPoints[j]["longitude"]));
addpoint.Parameters.AddWithValue("@streetname", snappedPoints[j]["name"].ToString());
addpoint.Parameters.AddWithValue("@longlat", SqlGeography.STGeomFromText(new SqlChars(string.Format("POINT({0} {1})", snappedPoints[j]["latitude"], snappedPoints[j]["longitude"])), Helper.SRID));
addpoint.Parameters[4].UdtTypeName = "Geography";
addpoint.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Hope this solves all your problems.

Yet another side note is to use Helper.SRID = 4326 for the provided string format.

Comment: I tried with the space, but I am getting the same error. I have edited the question with the error message, Actually it is not an error message but the program is exited. I have added the table schema as well to the question now.

Comment: While these are correct and necessary amendments, the error happens before the command has a chance to execute, at `SqlGeography.STGeomFromText`.

Comment: @GSerg yes you are correct and so have I added the solution to the actual problem as well.

Comment: @Sree do check the latest update which I believe will help.

Comment: @Tayyab I don't see how adding `.UdtTypeName = "Geography"`, either before or after `AddWithValue`, could affect the outcome of `SqlGeography.STGeomFromText` which is not concerned with SqlCommands at all.

Comment: I tried to mimic the problem on my machine for the provided schema and code and faced the same exception which I was able to get rid of specifying the UdtTypeName  for the SqlGeography type parameter.